# How to check a semigroup, monoid

Tags: group-theory

In my course textbook, it is mentioned that semigroups are algebraic systems that obey closure and associative property. But in the formal definition for semigroups, closure property is not mentioned. So if i have to check whether  is a semigroup do i have to check both closure and associativity?

Comment: "closure" is redundant as that is part of being an operation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. If you are being asked to prove that something is a semi-group then you do have to check that it is closed under the operation. Some people say that the term "binary operation" inherently implies closure under that operation.

Either way, you do actually have to prove both closure and associativity, when proving that a semi group is a semi group. In the formal definition you have checked, they have probably included an implication of closure in their definition of the operation.